# Is it possible to map this kind of plot in R?

Tags: r

Here is what the data frame looks like.

```
    time density
1    100    1.00
2    101    1.09
3    102    1.18
4    103    1.27
5    104    1.36
6    105    1.45
7    106    1.54
8    107    1.63
9    108    1.72
10   109    1.81
```

There first column is the time series and the second represents the corresponding density value.Any way to plot this kind of plot bellow in R? The horizontal direction represents the time series and vertical color is the corresponding density.

see the model template here
[image]

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried yourself?

Comment: I honestly do not have any idea how to do that. If you know something, please tell me. Thanks sincerely.

Comment: Have you tried a stacked barplot with ggplot, done horizontally?  Or perhaps a heat map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in any way what you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(time),y="something",fill=density)) +geom_tile() + coord_fixed()
p1
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. Suggestion 1: if this satisfies you, could you accept the answer? (Not to beat my own drum, but to keep others from spending time on it). Suggestion 2: please don't assume everyone on SO is male.